# Redundant Code Optimization

Tags: android, android-fragments

We have BaseActivity and BaseFragment. We have toolbar(In some cases we have to include toolbar in Fragment itself) in both Activity and Fragment. We have written all boiler plate code(findingviews and setter methods to set toolbar title,toolbar navigation icon) in BaseActivity and BaseFragment. Since its the **same toolbar layout used in both Activity and Fragment, code is same in both places which is redundant**.

How do we **optimise it so that we can write all the boiler plate code in one common place and use it in both Activity and Fragment**. Since code is redundant now, we have to make changes in both BaseActivity and BaseFragment. Please let me know how we can optimise it. Thank you.

Comment: You move the code to a new class and call it from both places.

Comment: i don't really get it, you need to be clearer on your code architecture, if you are talking about Fragments inside an Activity then why you should set the toolbar twice? if what you want to achieve is just code the toolbar once and use it multiple time you can just create one toolbar and use include.

Comment: @Henry Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq I have a scenario, where an Activity contains 2 Fragments and both fragments have there own toolbar.

Comment: @NageshJatagond does it have to be toolbar ? you can simply use Linearlayout or other container and mimik the toolbar, except you want to perform native toolbar element like menu item or searchview etc, which can also be done without toolbar.